# How do you summon chests with loot tables with command blocks in Minecraft v1.10.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was using the command below to summon it and already had put the loot json in my Minecraft folder, but it would still only spawn empty chests.

```
/setblock ~ ~2 ~ minecraft:chest 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{LootTable:"mctools:chests/NorthDungeon1"}}
```

Comment: We'll need more information than that. We need the loot table being used, the filepath on disk, and error messages in the output log. Also be aware that some operating systems will require the filepath to be in lowercase.

Comment: There are no errors, it simply summons the chest and says everything was run correctly. As for the filepath, I'm confused on what that would be...isn't it just the part in quotations at the end of the command?

Comment: Not an error in the command block, but an error in the output log (you have to enable output log visibility in your launcher if you don't already do that). The filepath to the actual file on your computer (disk), not in the command. There's a *lot* that can go wrong when a loot table fails, so we need every bit of information (including the entire JSON loot table).

Answer (score 2):

FIX:

```
/setblock ~ ~2 ~ minecraft:chest 1 0 {LootTable:"mctools:chests/NorthDungeon1"}
```

Your problem was you where trying to merge the `/give` and `/setblock` command together.

Comment: I tried this with some custom loot table, too, and I'm still an empty chest. Is there a way to see any error message that may come from the loot table definition? My command console didn't throw any message other than the chest being summoned/placed.